# django xadmin m2m filter_horizontal not working

Tags: django

I am trying to get `filter_horizontal` to work with `xadmin`, but for some reason it does not work if I just type in:

```
filter_horizontal = ('someField',)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well like always! Right after posting my question I ACTUALLY start reading the source code of [xadmin](https://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin/blob/master/xadmin/plugins/multiselect.py) and see that all you have to do it the following :

```
style_fields = {'someField': 'm2m_transfer'}
```